# How to convert int to VARTYPE?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, type-conversion

I've got

```
vt = x;
```

And

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data
```

But the code works enough stable so how can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: which compiler you are using ? I think there must be some switch in the compiler settings to ignore these warnings..

Comment: How is `VARTYPE` defined?

Comment: I use msvc. I think I can do #pragma warning(push) -> disable 4244 -> pop but is it the only way?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I can find `typedef unsigned short VARTYPE;` in `WTypes.h` and `afxwin.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'VARTYPE', possible loss of data
```

This indicates that `int` is wider than `VARTYPE` and you're losing precision by executing this cast.

> But the code works enough stable

If you want to give yourself confidence that this is indeed a safe operation, you should make sure you execute tests which cover a wide range of values for `x`.  If your target uses 32-bit `int` then you should make sure you hit values like `2^16`, `2^32-1` and still get the expected results.  If `x` represents a quantity, this operation will mean that for values outside of the range which can be represented by `VARTYPE`, you will instead get a value which can be represented by `VARTYPE`.

For example, if `VARTYPE` is stored as a 16-bit word and `int` is stored as a 32-bit word, then as the value of `x` grows from 65535 to 65536, `vt` will instead reset (from `65535` to `0`).

EDIT: You indicate that `VARTYPE` is an `unsigned short`, so be sure to avoid comparisons between variables declared as `int` and `VARTYPE`.

Comment: I see... Thanks, Though I also need to review if `int` is necessary for `x`.